# How to highlight TextView when CheckBox is pressed?

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout that contains CheckBox and TextView. I want to highlight TextView when CheckBox is pressed.

**Layout and selector (in drawable folder)**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkPlayStop"
            android:button="@drawable/play_stop_state" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPlayStop"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_view_state" />

</LinearLayout>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/grey" />
</selector>
```

Target: When I tap within the layout - checkbox change state and textview highlights.

Thanks.

Comment: post your relevant code :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set `OnCheckedChangeListener` on the `checkbox` as follows:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if (isChecked)
        {
            //Highlight the text
            textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        } else
        {
            //Unhighlight the text
            textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yourCheckBox);

cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }else{
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

  }
});
```

I don't exactly know how you want to highlight the textview so the example only contains a new background color.

Comment: You need to declare your TextView with final keyword to access within onClick() in click listener

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight your text view by changing Text colour, putting a background or changing your text type like Bold etc.

For changing background you can use `textView.setBackgroundColor(your color code)`.

For changing Text type you can use `textView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD)`

For changing Text color, you can use `textView.setTextColor(your color code`)

use this code at the place shown in above answers inside checkChangedListener.